# Assign the list to a variable followed by a comma is equivalent to access the entry of the list, what is the name of this kind of Python feature

Tags: python

this is a simple list

```
>>> list_1 = [1]
>>> list_1
[1]
```

Assign the list to a variable followed by a comma

```
>>> tmp, = list_1
>>> tmp
1
```

is equivalent to access the entry of the list.

what is the name of this kind of feature.

Comment: Perhaps reading [PEP-3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) can be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called `unpacking` in Python.

```
def fn(one, two, three):
    print(one, two, three)

my_args = [1, 2, 3]

fn(*my_args)

one, two, three = my_args
print(one, two, three)

fn(one, two, three)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

---

For more details:

- Read [PEP-3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), as Chris has mentioned in his comment.
- Search `Python unpack a list into variables` on the internet.